# Another proof of Menger's theorem?

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

**Menger's Theorem.** *Let $u$ and $v$ be nonadjacent vertices in a graph $G$. The minimum number of vertices in a u−v separating set is s. One can find $s$ internally disjoint $u$−$v$ paths in $G$.*

I tried to proof this using induction: the theorem is trivial when $s=1$. If the theorem is true when $s=l$, then, when $s=l+1$, we first find $l$ internally disjoint $u$−$v$ paths in $G$, $p_1,p_2,\dots,p_l$. The second vertices of $p_1, p_2, \dots, p_l$ doesn't separate $u$ and $v$, so there is another path $q_1$ between $u$ and $v$. If $q_1$ doesn't intersect with any $p_i$, $\{q_1,p_1,p_2,\dots,p_l\}$ is what we need. So we assume $q_1$ intersects with some $p_i$'s.

Now for all $p_i$, find the last intersection with all $q_i$'s. (If there are none, choose a random vertex.) This set of *l* points doesn't separate $u$ and $v$. So there's another path from $u$ to $v$, $q_2$. Notice that $q_2$ can't intersect a $p_i$ before $q_1$ does.

Repeat the above process. Notice that when some $q_{r-1}$ intersects every $p_i$ at the last vertex of $p_i$, one could finally find a $q_r$, which doesn't intersect with any $p_i$.

Is my thought correct, or should be corrected? How can I make this proof more rigorous?

Comment: Just a comment on your statement: It says The number of $u−v$ separating sets is $s$, but should say `The minimum number of vertices in a $u-v$ separating set is $s$' or something like that rather.

Comment: Corrected @BrandonduPreez